# what is the success response after a transaction with square up php process payment

Tags: php, api, sandbox, square-connect

i am recieveing this response after a transaction but i am not able to find the success or failure response,also i am not aware of the flow please correct me if i am wrong,

1. we have a sandbox account on square up we have an ecommerce web.
2. store with buy now option  after submitting the form with nounce and
       correction location id we are moved to process payments file where.
3. it displays the response after a transaction is made.

**Response**

```
SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse Object
(
[errors:protected] => 
[transaction:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
    (
        [id:protected] => 1d034209-12cf-5d13-72f4-62247bb49132
        [location_id:protected] => CBASEB5G76QcIpEWB0w38Mi2vWUgAQ
        [created_at:protected] => 2017-07-27T05:45:34Z
        [tenders:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                    (
                        [id:protected] => 675e208b-caf3-5f11-7482-1eacff13da64
                        [location_id:protected] => CBASEB5G76QcIpEWB0w38Mi2vWUgAQ
                        [transaction_id:protected] => 1d034209-12cf-5d13-72f4-62247bb49132
                        [created_at:protected] => 2017-07-27T05:45:34Z
                        [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                        [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                            (
                                [amount:protected] => 100
                                [currency:protected] => USD
                            )

                        [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                        [customer_id:protected] => 
                        [type:protected] => CARD
                        [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                            (
                                [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                    (
                                        [id:protected] => 
                                        [card_brand:protected] => DISCOVER
                                        [last_4:protected] => 9697
                                        [exp_month:protected] => 
                                        [exp_year:protected] => 
                                        [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                        [billing_address:protected] => 
                                        [fingerprint:protected] => 
                                    )

                                [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                            )

                        [cash_details:protected] => 
                    )

            )

        [refunds:protected] => 
        [reference_id:protected] => 
        [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
        [client_id:protected] => 
        [order:protected] => 
        [shipping_address:protected] => 
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you checked their documentation? Talked to them about it?

Comment: i have checked the documentation and reached this far,but i cant find a way to get the transaction status.

Comment: How to verify the transaction: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-checkout-getstarted#verify

Comment: ok thanks for the link,but cant we see our transcations on the sandbox account,i have used transaction api to fetch all my transcations but i cant see it on sandbox dashboard like we can see on paypal

Comment: Dashboard? You really need to update your question because I have _no idea_ what your actual issue is or what it is your asking...

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but im really new to this thing, wont we be able to see the transactions here? https://squareup.com/dashboard/sales/transactions

Comment: That's not a programming question. That's a support question you should ask the API provider (Square up). SO is for programming and when you're having issues with your _code_. It's not a general customer support for all services on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a transaction back, then your request was successful. If you get errors back, your request was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

you ll get Transaction id return to the Redirect URL